# What's the purpose of Task.FromCanceled

Tags: c#, .net

I'm new to **TPL**, and confused with the purpose of `Task`'s static `FromXXX` methods:

```
public class Task : ... 
{
   public static Task FromCanceled(CancellationToken cancellationToken);
   public static Task FromException(Exception exception);
   public static Task<TResult> FromResult<TResult>(TResult result);
}
```

Let's take `Task.FromCanceled` for example, why do we need this one? When we create a `Task`, we want to execute something, so what's the purpose of creating an canceled task that won't ever do anything?

Comment: _"What's the purpose of creating an cancled task that can do nothing?"_ - Perhaps you find a situation where you need to? You could ask the same of `FromException`.

Comment: most simple use case: you're designing a unit test to verify some code behaves correctly when a task it requested was cancelled.

Comment: Probably because you need to implement some async interface method, but you don't actually need to await anything.

Comment: please review [don't ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask) regarding the kinds of questions you should avoid asking.  This question is being posed as an open-ended, hypothetical question without focus; therefore will have many equally valid answers.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here's an example. You have a library that declares a method as returning `Task`, with a view of using `async`/`await`:

```
public interface IFoo
{
    Task BarAsync(CancellationToken token);
}
```

But your code / unit test method is synchronous and has nothing to await, so we can therefore implement it with `Task.FromResult`, etc.

```
public class MyFoo : IFoo
{
    public Task BarAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        if (cancellationToken.IsCancellationRequested)
        {
            return Task.FromCanceled(cancellationToken);
        }
        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }
}
```

Note that you can also find examples of things like this in the wild. [GitHub search](https://github.com/search?l=C%23&q=Task.FromCanceled&type=Code)

For example, [this code](https://github.com/NoaFeiger/Chat/blob/a568ba1022603c05ad548c2933d806efda0b84bc/Json110r1/Source/Src/Newtonsoft.Json/JsonWriter.Async.cs#L118-L127) uses it in a similar scenario to what I described above.

Answer (score 2):

Here's an example.

Let's say I have a method that takes a long time, that follows with another method. If I want to cancel the process and don't want the second method to run I might need to return a cancelled task.

Like this:

```
Task<string> query =
    from t in Task.Run(() => GetLongRunningValue())
    from x in cts.IsCancellationRequested
        ? Task.FromCanceled<string>(cts.Token) 
        : Task.Run(() => t + "!")
    select x;
```

---

Here's the code that let's you use LINQ with Tasks:

```
public static class TaskEx
{
    public static Task<R> Select<T, R>(this Task<T> task, Func<T, R> s) => task.ContinueWith(t => s(t.Result));
    public static async Task<R> SelectMany<T, R>(this Task<T> task, Func<T, Task<R>> k) => await k(await task);
    public static async Task<R> SelectMany<T, U, R>(this Task<T> task, Func<T, Task<U>> k, Func<T, U, R> s)
    {
        var t = await task;
        var u = await k(t);
        return s(t, u);
    }
}
```